# ManyToOne: deleteAll() & delete(object) not working

Tags: spring-boot, jpa-2.0, crud

I'm trying to get a ManyToOne relation to work, every other relation does work except this one. It's a list of accounts that are mapped to a person.

Problems:

-When I try to save an Account:

```
Account accountSave = AccountRepository.save(account); //works
```

-When I try to save multiple Account:

```
Account accountASave = AccountRepository.save(accountA);
Account accountBSave = AccountRepository.save(accountB);
//not working: results in : Expected <2> but was:<4>
```

-When I try to delete an Account:

```
Account accountSave = AccountRepository.save(account);
AccountRepository.delete(account);
//does not delete the account
```

When I try to delete all Accounts:

```
Account accountASave = AccountRepository.save(accountA);
Account accountBSave = AccountRepository.save(accountB);
AccountRepository.deleteAll();
//deleted instance passed to merge
```

- When I try to save a Clerk: works
- When I try to save multiple Clerks: works
- When I try to delete a Clerk: works
- When I try to delete all Clerks: works
      (every time is the same strategy used as above)

I tried to fiddle with cascadeType but no luck

=> changing: `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to

```
cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.REMOVE}
```

does not solve the problem

- adding `@Transaction` to the transaction methods does not solve any
  problem
- adding `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` to Account does not
  help either

OneToMany relation:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class Clerk extends Werknemer {

    private String salary;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clerk", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    (...)
}
```

ManyToOne relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNTS")
public class Account implements Serializable, Comparable<Account>{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clerk_id")
    private Clerk clerk;

    private String text;

    (...)
}
```

deleteAll() & delete(object) has to work and
saving 2 account and not 4 when I try to save 2 accounts
unit test:

```
'    @Test
public void DeleteAccount() {
    Account account = new Account();
    account.setTekst("Tekst");

    Bediende bediende = new Bediende();
    bediende.setBedrijfsnaam("Bedrijfsnaam");
    bediende.setNaam("Naam");
    bediende.setVoornaam("Voornaam");
    bediende.setPersoneelsnummer(12345678);
    bediende.setSalaris("Salaris");

    Werkadres werkadres = new Werkadres();
    werkadres.setGemeente("Gemeente");
    werkadres.setHuisnummer("Huisnummer");
    werkadres.setPostcode("Postcode");
    werkadres.setStraat("Straat");

    bediende.setWerkadres(werkadres);

    account.setBediende(bediende);

    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    accounts.add(account);


    bediende.setAccounts(accounts);

    Account accountSave = accrep.save(account);
    accrep.delete(account);

    Iterable<Account> accountLijst = accrep.findAll();
    for (Account a : accountLijst) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
    accrep.deleteAll();
}'
```

Comment: Could not reproduce this, works perfectly fine in my case

Comment: I've added a unit test